# How to get a function's argument names in Python without importing inspect (or any other modules)

Tags: python, python-import, built-in

In a web-app that I am using I can write Python script and I have access to some libraries, which contain some functions I want to use. However, the web-app seems to restrict a lot of "normal" python capacities, including some imports.

The trouble is that I can't get my hands on the documentation for the libraries that I can use. Let's use the `FileUtils` library as am example of a non-standard library I am allowed  to import.

I managed to get a list of methods using `dir(FileUtils)`.

Now I could see that what I'm probably looking for is `getFile`, and through some trail and error, I'm pretty sure it takes two arguments, of which the first one is a string of the file path.

I am stuck on what else I must input and I am hoping that if I can just see the argument name, that might give it away. (I've tried `'r'`, but to no avail.) I know that normally the `inspect`  module would help me out, but the web-app crashes when I try to import it. Hence the question.

Comment: how about `help`?

Comment: Use the `help()` function.  E.g. `help(FileUtils.getFile)`

Comment: If the package is not in the standard library, it must have been installed and imported before it is available in your app. If it is open source, you could clone the repository and have a look at the source code and the definitions.

Comment: "Python script" and "restricted access" sounds familiar.. do you work on a Zope/Plone application?

Comment: @J.G. : No, I work on something called ETQ Reliance

Comment: @James: yes, I have also tried using `help(FileUtils.getFile)`, but the webapp does not like that either. It logs an error `OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace`

Comment: Unfortunately somebody closed this question... :-( `your_function.func_code.co_argcount` or `your_function.func_code.co_varnames`

Comment: @J.G.: what is `func_code` ? I tried this in a sandbox, but can't get it to work there...

Comment: `func_code` is an attribute of a function - but it only works on CPython 2 - what Python do you run? For Python 3 it is `your_function.__code__.co_argcount` and `your_function.__code__.co_varnames`